# Log4j2 Automatically Log all console outputs

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

Is there anyway that I can configure to log4j2 properties file to have it automatically log all console outputs? The current legacy program I am working on has a lot of console outputs and I would like to set log4j2 to automatically log these outputs to a file if possible. Without using System.setout. that is.

Thank you!

Comment: Try to give as much information as possible. Are you using any frameworks? Spring Boot for instance? Properties file or YAML?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. System.out is an OutputStream. You can set System.out to an OutputStream you control. You can then log all the data coming in to that and send it to files using the logging configuration. However, if you do that you must not use the Console appender or you will end up in an endless loop.